# SQL Collation conflict ... can you force only 1 database to use a different SYSTEM level default?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I know there are several threads that discuss SQL Collation Conflict but I believe this is a bit different.

I have a SHARED SQL Server (2016) set up per Microsoft's recommendation of "Latin1_General_CI_AS" instead of the legacy "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS". About half the database on the server are running the newer Collation and the other half the Legacy. **Everything has been working fine for a long time!**

However, now I am trying to host another 3rd Party's database and for whatever reason, it refuses to work. Their Software keeps crashing and complains about not being able to translate Collations (or something along those lines).

From my understanding, individual databases can specify their own Collation (obviously since we are about 50/50 now already), however any sort of Temp tables and such that a software solution creates, which I'm assuming includes queries, will be done under the Server's Default Collation.

I tried changing this new databases Collation over to match the Server but their software still threw the same error. So right now, the Vendor's suggestion is to change the Default of the Server back to the older Collation. I'm cannot risk breaking all of the existing solutions that have been running fine for years, to accommodate this one product.

**So finally, my question**:

Is there some backdoor trick that would force this Database and all its access to use "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" instead, even while the SQL Instance's default remains "Latin1_General_CI_AS"?

Comment: What the vendor should be doing is ensuring that any temp tables they create have string columns set to `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` - you could try making it a [partially contained database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations?view=sql-server-ver15#contained-databases) and see if that patches things up enough

Comment: Using `alter database db_name collate ...` to change the database's default collation will not affect the collation of any existing **user** columns in it. It does change the collation used for **system** columns, then only newly created user columns that don't specify a particular collation will inherit it. The whole change collation process is rather messy because it involves dropping indexes (and FK/PK constraints where applicable), changing the collation of all user columns and then recreating all of the indexes (and PK/FK constraints).

Comment: Thanks all. I think the only real option here is to install a new instance of SQL just to run this specific vendor's database. I hate the idea, but it would resolve everything.

Comment: Wanted to mention that the comment @Martin Smith made about Partially Contained Databases MAY work. Been digging into this a bit more, and there are several things you can do with contained databases, and some Gotcha's, but at least following Microsofts Example, I was able to reproduce the same error, and then once I put the MS example into Partial Contained, the error went away.... have to try this now with the Vendor's database and see if something else breaks.